# Rasterize polygon shapefile giving cells average value of overlapping geometries

Tags: raster, r, rasterization, gdal-rasterize

I want to rasterize a polygon shapefile in r - loaded as an `sf`. Using `stars`, I can do `st_rasterize` to create a stars object snapped to a template raster, which is great because I the next step I want to complete is multiplying both datasets.

The polygon shapefile has several geometries that are smaller than the resolution of the output raster. When this happens, the raster's cell is given the value of the cell's centroid. This can be clearly understood looking at this image that shows the output of the st_rasterize operation - those cells with their centers falling on the river (aka without a geometry in their centroid) have been returned with an NA value.

[image]

Is there a way I could rasterize the `sf` object at the same resolution, but in a way that the output cells have the average value of the overlapping geometries? **There are two ways this could be done:**

a) a more desirable outcome would be a **weighted** average by which the ratio of overlap is considered in the averaging

b) a simple average value without considering the overlap ratio (less desirable, but maybe more achievable).

I feel like this question might have part of the answer, but since I am running in R I am not 100% sure how to implement it. Perhaps using `gdal_rasterize` from `gdalUtils`?

**Edit**
I know this could be achieved using a vector grid, but the size of the are of study will make it problematic (several million cells). Because of this, I am trying to avoid this avenue, but I am open to suggestions if you know how to make such process efficient / light on computational needs.